# If $d$ is the order of $a$ modulo $n$ then prove that $n| \Phi_d(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

> Let $a$ be an integer such that $gcd(a,n)=1$. Prove that $\displaystyle \text{ord}_n(a)=d$ if and only if $\displaystyle n| \Phi_d(a)$ ; where , $\text{ord}_n(a)$ is the order of $a$ modulo $n$ and $\Phi_n(x)$ denotes the $n$-th Cyclotomic polynomial.

From definition of $\text{ord}_n(a)$, we know that $d$ is the least positive integer such that $a^d \equiv 1\pmod n$. Then how I proceed ? Any hint. ?

**Edit:**  I've stuck in the converse part to show **$d$ is the smallest** such that .....

Suppose that $n|\Phi_d(a)=a^d-1$.That is $a^d \equiv 1\pmod n$. Now I want to show that $d$ is the least positive integer satisfying this congruence.

Comment: The following identity might be useful: for all $n\geq 1$, $X^n-1=\displaystyle\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d,$ where $d$ runs through the set of positive divisors of $n$.

Comment: I know the identity but how it helps ?

Comment: Note that in your case, $a^d-1$ is divisible by $n$.  Now use the formula in the above comment...

Comment: @SteveD Thanks for hint. I've done the first part. But for the converse part?

Comment: $\Phi_d(a) = a^d -1$ is not true in general.

Comment: @i707107 $x^n-1=\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x)$.Then , $a^d-1=\prod_{d|d}\Phi_d(a)=\Phi_d(a)$

Comment: @Topo, you're mixing two instances of $d$. Try with $x^n-1=\prod_{e|n}\Phi_e(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true if $n$ is not a prime. For example, take $n=15$. Then
$$
2^1=2, 2^2=4, 2^3=8, 2^4=1 \ \textrm{mod}\  15.
$$

Thus, $\mathrm{ord}_{15}(2) = 4$. However, $\Phi_4(2)=2^2+1 = 5$ and $15 \nmid 5$.

If $n$ is a prime, say $n=p$.  We work over the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. It is well-known that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has a primitive root $g$, and by Fermat's little theorem, any $a\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ is a root of $x^{p-1}-1=0$ mod $p$.

If $\mathrm{ord}_p(a)=d$, then $d|p-1$ and $a=g^j$ with $j=\frac{p-1}d k$ with $(k,d)=1$, $1\leq k \leq d$. Such $a$ is precisely the roots of $\Phi_d(x)=0$. This can be proved by $x^{p-1}-1=\prod_{d|p-1} \Phi_d(x)$. Any $a \in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ is a root of $\Phi_d(x)$ for some $d|p-1$. Moreover, each $\Phi_d(x)$ can have at most $\phi(d)$ roots where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient function. , Your statements is therefore true when $n$ is a prime $p$.

Comment: Sorry for mistake. Now please see my edited question and give some hint on particular point.

Comment: It already fails for $n=8, a=3$.